# Coproducts and products are same in any preadditive category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Here is the proof that coproducts and products are same in any preadditive category from the Stack project.

[image]

I have few questions regarding the above proof.
I don't understand what do they mean by *morphism corresponding to $(0,1)$*?

Also, I don't see how the mapping they get from $Mor(x,w) \times Mor(y,w)$ to $Mor(z,w)$ is actually a bijection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. We have the projections $p:x\times y\to x$ and $q:x\times y\to y$, which satisfy the universal property that any pair $f:a\to x,\ g:a\to y$ correponds to a unique arrow $a\to x\times y$. Now this is applied with $(f,g)=(1,0)$ as for $i:x\to z$ and with $(f,g)=(0,1)$ as for $j:y\to z$ where $0$ is the zero morphism and $1$ is the identity. 
   By this definition, importantly, we have the following equations:
   $$p\circ i=1_x,\quad q\circ i=0,\\ p\circ j=0,\quad q\circ j=1_y$$
2. The mapping $\def\Mor{\mathrm{Mor}}\Mor(x,w)\times\Mor(y,w)\to\Mor(z,w)$ is just given above, call it $\Phi\ :=\ (a,b)\mapsto a\circ p\,+\,b\circ q$. 

   **Hint:** Use the equations in 1. to find the inverse for $\Phi$.