# A different definition of coproduct in a category

Tags: category-theory, direct-sum, additive-categories

I am following Pavel et al book "Tensor Categories". They write that an *additive category* is a category $\mathcal{C}$ such that:

[image]

My problem is with (A3). i know that what they are trying to say is that all bicoproducts exist. But I do not see how that is equivalent to what they wrote: as far as I understand, the coproduct $X_1\rightarrow X_1\sqcup X_2\leftarrow X_2$ is such that for every other pair of arrows $X_1\rightarrow Y\leftarrow X_2$ we have an unique arrow $f$ such that
[image]

commutes.

I do not see how to connect this with what they say in (A3).

Comment: Maybe this question and the one linked to it could help : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1586786/coproducts-and-products-are-same-in-any-preadditive-category.

Comment: It's a standard result which you can find in Freyd's book on abelian categories as well as almost any reference on that topic, or most in general category theory, that a biproduct is an object satisfying those conditions. Note that this isn't only a coproduct, but simultaneously a product.

Comment: To complement Kevin's comment, it is Theorem VIII.2.2, p194-195 in CWM (second edition) and Theorem 2.42, p50 in Freyd's "Abelian categories" (which, by the way, is freely available [here](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/3/tr3abs.html)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author is here  using to their advantage the fact that there is an additive structure.

Indeed, let me use the notations of A3, and let $Z$ be an object with maps $f_i: X_i\to Z$. 
Then consider the map $Y\to Z$ defined by $f=f_1\circ p_1+f_2\circ p_2$.

One may check at once that $f\circ i_1 = f_1\circ p_1\circ i_1 + f_2\circ p_2 \circ i_1 = f_1  + f_2\circ 0 = f_1$ (indeed one may prove that $p_2\circ i_1 = 0$ using the fact that $i_2$ is a monomorphism), and similarly $f\circ i_2 = f_2$, and if $g$ satisfies those equations, then $g= g\circ i_1\circ p_1 + g\circ i_2\circ p_2 = f_1\circ p_1 + f_2\circ p_2 = f$, thus our map $f$ is unique.

This shows that $(Y,i_1,i_2)$ is a coproduct in the usual sense. Similarly you may prove that $(Y,p_1,p_2)$ is a product in the usual sense. This is what makes it a biproduct.

Comment: I do not see why you would assume that $i_2$ is a mono. Why not instead do as MacLane?: $p_2 i_1 = p_2(i_1p_1 + i_2 p_2)i_1 = p_2 i_1 + p_2 i_1$ so that $p_2 i_1 = 0$

Comment: I do not assume $i_2$ is mono, you can prove it because $p_2i_2=id$ is mono, therefore $i_2$ is as well

Comment: Understood, thanks.